# Remove reminder

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is there anyway to remove a reminder/alarm that has been created from my application? And maybe make it possible for the user to list all reminders/alarms that has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
if (ScheduledActionService.Find("Your Alarm Name") != null)
ScheduledActionService.Remove("Your Alarm Name");
```